# Issue In Parsing Simple JSON Array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to figure this out for what seems like forever. My PHP is working fine. As an example, it returns the following if I select "Grove Bow" from my select dropdown:

```
[{"wtype":"Grove Bow","was":"1.55","wcc":"5","wbdmin":"12","wbdmax":"37"}]
```

The issue is in parsing the data in the success callback function in my .js file where I have written:

```
$.post("get.php",
    {w:wname},
    function(data) {
        was = data[1].was;
        wcc = data[2].wcc;
        wbdmin = data[3].wbdmin;
        wbdmax = data[4].wbdmax;
        console.log($.parseJSON(data));
    }
);
```

The console returns what I believe to be an empty array:

```
[Object]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

If I remove the *$.parseJSON()* the console returns the same result that was posted by my get.php file:

```
[{"wtype":"Grove Bow","was":"1.55","wcc":"5","wbdmin":"12","wbdmax":"37"}]
```

I need to access these elements of the array as you can see by my attempt to store them as variables (don't worry, I declared them earlier at the top of my .js file).

Pliss halp!

Comment: The answer posted is correct, and beyond that, you can also use `}, 'json');` to have the data returned automatically parsed as json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console returns you array of objects

and `console.log($.parseJSON(data[0]));` will give you your object

Additionaly, you should access your data like this:

```
var data=$.parseJSON(data);
var myObj=data[0];  
var was=myObj.was;  
var wcc=myObj.wcc;  
//and etc
//or just data[0].was, data[0].wcc
```

and of course better way, like stated in comment, to use 'json' datatype, instead of calling parseJSON manually

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) :

> **data**
>
> > Type: PlainObject or String
> >     A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

PlainObject:
for the normal operation of a method, you must pass there object like:

```
{ 'someKey' : 'someVal' , 'sK2' : 'sV2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access string like it is an object.

Try this

```
$.post("get.php",
    {w:wname},
    function(data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data)[0];
        was = json.was;
        wcc = json.wcc;
        wbdmin = json.wbdmin;
        wbdmax = json.wbdmax;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery ajax part looks fine,
Try pure Javascript in your callback function:

```
function(data) {
   var json = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(json.wtype); //Grove Bow
   console.log(json.was); //1.55
   //and so on...
}
```